# How to change axis velocity during Gcode operation

Tags: automation, motion, codesys, cnc

Good work everyone,

I have been working on a 3 axis CNC machine for a while. A lot of things are going great! But I couldn't find how to increase or decrease the axis speeds while processing the g code. I am using the SMC_INTERPOLTAOR block to manipulate the G code. I think I can overcome this problem with the 'dwtime' value in the entry of this block, but this does not offer a healthy solution.

I need support for this! I need to do an instant increase or decrease of the axis speed during a motion!

Thanks. / ByCNC

What is motion axis speed control problem method

[image]

Comment: If you are using some specific API for a specific environment, at least give us those details, like, what environment are you using (TwinCat, CODESYS, Machine Expert..), what Codesys version are you using, what library and what's the version of the library with taht function?

Comment: I'm doing the work on codesys. I am using SM3 Basic and SM3 CNC libraries.

Comment: Have you tried using dOverride? `The scheduled velocity of the particular objects will get scaled by dOverride`

Comment: Yes! This worked for me. The solution is very simple but I haven't seen it. Programming is like that sometimes. Hey @Guiorgy I have another problem. Maybe you are also familiar with this issue. The problem is that when there are too many lines in the G code file, I get the SMC_CNC_INTERNAL_ERROR warning. This is the big problem.

Comment: I am using "SMC_NcInterpreter" block in codesys to read G code file. Do you know about this block or its usage?
Thanks a lot though.

Answer (score 1):

While I have no experience with SoftMotion CNC libraries, looking through the [documentation](https://content.helpme-codesys.com/en/libs/SM3_CNC/4.11.0.0/SM_CNC_POUs/SoftMotion-CNC/SoftMotion-Function-Blocks/SMC_Interpolator.html#smc-interpolator) the `dOverride` input argument seems to be promissing:

> ... The scheduled velocity of the particular objects will get scaled by dOverride; thus the scheduled velocity can be increased resp. reduced in online mode...

Comment: That's right @Guiorgy! Override works as a gain, which can vary from 0 to 1 (or it can go beyond that if the axes allow it), with 1 being exactly the speed set in parameter F of the G code (in user units), and 0.5 = 50 %...